# making a discord bot followed a tutorial and it dint work

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, discord

I'm using node.js and visual studio

the bot is seemingly not working but does respond to the node . command but doesn't respond to the -ping command and I can find out why, is it spelling or updated code or am I just stupid please help.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '-';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('sirjunkbot is awake');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('pong!');
    } else if (command == 'test'){
        message.channel.send('123');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the console say?
Also you dont have client.login()

Comment: i fiex it but should i have client login